# Spring Data JPA custom query with entity as a parameter doesn't work

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

When I use custom query with entity as parameter in Spring Data JPA I get the exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

Here are related entities. I have two entities with @OneToOne relationship, like below:

Car:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "car_id")
private long id;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id", unique = true, nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true)
private Order order;
...
}
```

Order:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order")
public class Order {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "order_id")
private long id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="order")
private Car car;
...
}
```

I have also Spring Data JPA repository with created custom query to find Order by Car:

```
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, Long> {

Optional<Order> findByCar(Car car);

}
```

However, when I use the method findByCar(carWithNonNullOrder), I get the error:

> 2016-01-28 12:13:39,494 [main           ] WARN  SqlExceptionHelper             - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 07001
>       2016-01-28 12:13:39,494 [main           ] ERROR SqlExceptionHelper             - No value specified for parameter 1
>       2016-01-28 12:13:39,503 [main           ] INFO  TransactionContext             - Rolled back transaction for test context [DefaultTestContext@61dde151 testClass = OrderServiceIT, testInstance = com.carsystem.server.OrderServiceIT@b25b095, testMethod = shouldMakeOrder@OrderServiceIT, testException = org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet, mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@507b79f7 testClass = OrderServiceIT, locations = '{classpath:context/app-context.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
>       2016-01-28 12:13:39,504 [main           ] INFO  GenericApplicationContext      - Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@ff5b51f: startup date [Thu Jan 28 12:13:31 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
>       2016-01-28 12:13:39,506 [main           ] INFO  tainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
>       org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:242)
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
>           at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
>           at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
>           at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
>           at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>           at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>           at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.findByCar(Unknown Source)
>           at com.carsystem.server.OrderMapper.map(OrderMapper.java:25)
>           at com.carsystem.server.OrderServiceImpl.listOrders(OrderServiceImpl.java:90)
>           at com.carsystem.server.OrderServiceIT.shouldMakeOrder(OrderServiceIT.java:96)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>           at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>           at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>           at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
>           at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
>           at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
>           at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
>           at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
>           at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>           at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
>           at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
>           at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
>           at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
>           at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
>           at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
>           at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106)
>           at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:79)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2116)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1899)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1875)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2611)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2594)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2423)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2418)
>           at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
>           at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326)
>           at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
>           at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
>           at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
>           at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:50)
>           at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:114)
>           at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
>           at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100)
>           at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91)
>           at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:462)
>           at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>           at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
>           at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
>           at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>           at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
>           ... 43 more
>       Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.checkAllParametersSet(PreparedStatement.java:2205)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2185)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.fillSendPacket(PreparedStatement.java:2115)
>           at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1936)
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
>           ... 74 more

It seems that Spring Data JPA proxy can't find the Car entity. I have found quite similar question here: [Spring Data query not working when query parameter is an entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28070640/spring-data-query-not-working-when-query-parameter-is-an-entity), but in my case I'm fetching entities eagerly. Is it something wrong with mappings or Spring Data JPA?

**EDIT**

Hibernate query: select order0_.order_id as order_i1_3_, order0_.client_id as client_i4_3_, order0_.createdDate as createdD2_3_, order0_.returnDate as returnDa3_3_ from order order0_ left outer join car car1_ on order0_.order_id=car1_.order_id where car1_.car_id=?

I have noticed that the parameter Car which I used in custom query is also a class member of Order entity. However, when I call the query, I have a circular dependency between Car and Order: Order had a null Car.

Comment: How can it even be a list? A Car has a single Order which has a single Car. So it cannot ever return a list.

Comment: I have replaced it with Optional<Order>, however that's not the case.

Comment: So no value was specified for some query parameter ... and WHAT WAS THE QUERY? The JPQL first, and then what SQL was it converted to by Hibernate?

Comment: "I have noticed that the parameter Car which I used in custom query is also a class member of Order entity. However, when I call the query .... Order had a null Car." So what are you saying. You are passing null as a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Order findOneByCar(Car car);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {

Order findByCar(Car car);

}
```

This should work.